# Could not find a sound of Super Mario Bros 3

Tags: super-mario-bros-3

I have searched anywhere on the web with no success.Where do I find the underwater theme in hurry up mode of Super Mario Bros 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was indeed elusive, but I found a video on it; The underwater tracks don't seem to be separate to the base songs and are just sped up in-game.